# Jenkins build gets failed, when unit test cases are failed

Tags: jenkins, mocha.js, jenkins-pipeline, html-reports-jenkins

**Jenkins build gets failed, when unit test cases are failed,
Here am using pipeline script in jenkins, Need to generate HTML report using mocha-awesome, I can get the HTML report only when all test cases are passed, Build fails if any functions failed in my testcases.[Here you can see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHi0x.png)**

Answer (score 0):

The call to the unit test run returns with exit status `1`.
What you can do is use the `returnStatus` option for the `sh` or `bat` step which will then not fail the build itself but leaves that up to you:

```
def exitStatus = sh returnStatus: true, script: 'unittests'
```

or:

```
def exitStatus = bat returnStatus: true, script: 'unittests.exe'
```

Having this you can selectively fail the build, i.e. if `exitStatus == 1` then ignore as it signals a test fail, if it is anything but `0` or `1` then fail the build using the `error` step.